# GitHub organization access via ssh key

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

Maybe I'm blind but I can't find a way to access an organization that has granted me access via SSH key. I know it's a breeze connecting directly to your own account but how would I go about doing this through an organization?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your account's personal SSH keys identify your GitHub user. If an organization has granted you access, it was done via your GitHub user; an SSH key attached to that user will give you access.

If you want to have separate SSH keys for your organization work (e.g. if you work on another machine), simply add the second key to your personal account.

Comment: Figured out it was my own issue. Since I was using a key other than default `id_rsa` I needed to start `ssh-agent` and run `ssh-add [key]`

Comment: @Chris that would mean im giving access to my organization to access my private repos :scary:

Comment: @PrathikJain, it does nothing of the sort. To do that, your organization would need your _private_ key, which you should always protect carefully.

Comment: @Chris this is only partially true. There is a security fault with this approach. Anyone in the organization can clone my personal private repositories. They cannot access my repo in a sense that they cannot list all my repositories, but if they guess the project link, they can clone it. (guessing the project name, is not that difficult)

Comment: @Ermal, that's completely untrue. What makes you think that?

Comment: @Chris Consider the 3 following actors: **Server** of the organization where Jenkins is running, my **Git Account**, **Organization's Git** profile. I am the owner of different organizations in Git. In the server the *pKey* is generated and the *pubKey* is added to my git profile.
Anyone who has access to the server machine, can clone any of my private repositories from all organizations I am owner of.

Comment: @Ermal, you're talking about a completely different workflow than what is described in the question. If you add _somebody else's_ SSH key to your GitHub profile then, yeah, that person can access your repositories. Don't do that. But that's not what's happening here. _**Never** share private keys._ (This question is about an organization granting your user access to certain repositories on GitHub. It has nothing to do with Jenkins or other CI tools. Nobody is sharing keys.)

Answer (score 2):

[According to Github](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-git-access-to-your-organizations-repositories),

> Support for SSH certificate authorities is available with GitHub Enterprise Cloud and GitHub Enterprise Server 2.19+. For more information, see "GitHub's products."

So if your organization account is not or cannot be subscribed to Enterprise plan (like if you're staying with either free or team plan) then you need to bypass github account as [@Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21395835/2626666) suggests. (You can do work-arounds making new dedicated Github user for organization, but it complicates security concern as organization's administrator have to take care for that, so maybe that approach is not a wise one.)

If another platform is a choice, [**bitbucket** allows you to do this for free per repository, not user](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/add-access-keys/). I use this on my Kiosk running on RaspberryPi so it to pull the update directly from repo. (My team is moving to Github's team
plan, so I'm torn apart in between changing deployment scheme to standard ways or keep this one repo on bitbucket for this one purpose.)

For **gitlab** though, it seems like it hasn't implemented this yet. ([Link to issued request.](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/19457))