# SSH access to github repo on codeship

Tags: bash, git, docker, ssh, codeship

I am attempting to push to github from a container on Codeship. After getting a `Permission denied (publickey)` error, I followed the suggestion here:

https://documentation.codeship.com/pro/builds-and-configuration/setting-ssh-private-key/

I created a service called `publish` to and some steps to try to recreate the article's suggestion.

My codeship_services.yml file:

```
# codeship_services.yml
publish:
  build: 
    image: codeship/setting-ssh-key-test
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.publish
  encrypted_env_file: codeship.env.encrypted
  volumes:
    - ./.ssh:/root/.ssh
```

My codeship_steps.yml file:

```
- name: temp publish service
  service: publish
  command: /bin/bash -c "echo -e $PRIVATE_SSH_KEY >> /root/.ssh/id_rsa"

- name: chmod id_rsa
  service: publish
  command: chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

- name: add server to list of known hosts
  service: publish
  command: /bin/bash -c "ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts"

- name: confirm ssh connection to server, authenticating with generated public ssh key
  service: publish
  command: /bin/bash -c "ssh -T git@github.com"
```

When running `jet steps`, however, I still get the `Permission denied (publickey)` error:

```
(step: temp_publish_service) success ✔
(step: chmod_id_rsa) 
(step: chmod_id_rsa) success ✔
(step: add_server_to_list_of_known_hosts) 
(service: publish) (step: add_server_to_list_of_known_hosts) # github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-80573d3e
(service: publish) (step: add_server_to_list_of_known_hosts) # github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-80573d3e
(service: publish) (step: add_server_to_list_of_known_hosts) # github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-80573d3e
(step: add_server_to_list_of_known_hosts) success ✔
(step: confirm_ssh_connection_to_server,_authenticating_with_generated_public_ssh_key) 
(service: publish) (step: confirm_ssh_connection_to_server,_authenticating_with_generated_public_ssh_key) Permission denied (publickey).
(step: confirm_ssh_connection_to_server,_authenticating_with_generated_public_ssh_key) error ✗
(step: confirm_ssh_connection_to_server,_authenticating_with_generated_public_ssh_key) container exited with a 255 code
```

I have generated the keys as instructed in the article and added the encrypted private key to `codeship.env.encryped`.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only missing step would be to register the [public Key on your GitHub account itself](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

Only then an SSH connection using that same public key would have a chance to succeed.

If not, try at least an `ssh -Tvv git@github.com` in your last step, in order to get more clues.

Comment: Thank you @VonC! If this repo is part of an org, does the key go under "Deploy keys"? I don't see a place for ssh keys on the org's repo.

Comment: @Tyler https://stackoverflow.com/a/21395835/6309: your own account should be enough, provided your GitHub account is part of the Organization.